# How to print complete date field in biblatex-chicago?

Tags: biblatex-chicago, date

I'm trying to to get biblatex-chicago to print out some nonstandard date formats as I've written them in Zotero before exporting to a .bib file:

1971 (2006)

2016a

2016b

Originally Zotero exported the first example as 1971 and erased the date from the second two. So I manually reinserted the dates as above in the .bib file, and now all print in pdflatex as "n.d."

How can I print these dates simply as I've written them? I need to export the formatted bibliography directly from Zotero for a website as well as LaTeX, which is why I've written the dates as I have. Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,nobib]{tufte-book}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

% Bibliography
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,doi=true,url=true,isbn=false,datelabel=comp]{biblatex-chicago}
\appto{\bibsetup}{\raggedright}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\AtEveryBibitem{
      \ifentrytype{online}
        {}
        {\clearfield{urlyear}\clearfield{urlmonth}\clearfield{urlday}}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  bibliography = {References}
}

\begin{document}

Some chapters.

\backmatter
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

and the .bib file:

```
@incollection{cardew_treatise_1971,
    location = {Essex},
    title = {Treatise Handbook},
    pages = {95--134},
    booktitle = {Cornelius Cardew: A Reader},
    publisher = {Copula},
    author = {Cardew, Cornelius},
    editor = {Prévost, Eddie},
    date = {1971 (2006)},
    keywords = {0, ostertag, treatise}
}

@article{wooley_anthony_????,
    title = {Anthony Coleman and Survivors Breakfast Explore Treatise},
    volume = {12},
    url = {http://soundamerican.org/sa_archive/sa12/sa12-the-treatise-performances.html},
    journaltitle = {Sound American},
    author = {Wooley, Nate},
    date = {2016a},
    keywords = {treatise}
}

@article{wooley_mostly_????,
    title = {Mostly Other People Do The Killing Are Detained By Treatise},
    volume = {12},
    url = {http://soundamerican.org/sa_archive/sa12/sa12-the-treatise-performances.html},
    journaltitle = {Sound American},
    author = {Wooley, Nate},
    date = {2016b},
    keywords = {barrett, treatise}
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: bump bumpity bump

Comment: You really shouldn't write `2016a`/`2016b`, `biblatex` does that for you if necessary. You don't need `date = {1971 (2006)},` either, you can use a combination of `date` and `origdate`. Date-type fields must always be given in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, anything else will not parse correctly.

Comment: BTW: Commenting on your question won't bump it up again.

Answer (score 2):

`date` fields in  `biblatex` should be given in `YYYY-MM-DD` format (of course you can leave out information from right to left, so `YYYY-MM` and `YYYY` are fine as well).

So neither `2016a`, `2016b` nor `1971 (2006)` will parse correctly.

For the first two, you should just give `date = {2016}` and let `biblatex` append the letter automatically. If you insist on a certain order of the two entries that goes contrary to what you get from your sorting scheme, you can use `sortyear = {2016-1}` and `sortyear = {2016-2}` for that.

The `1971 (2006)` reads more like you should use `origdate`.

```
@incollection{cardew_treatise_1971,
  location  = {Essex},
  title     = {Treatise Handbook},
  pages     = {95--134},
  booktitle = {Cornelius Cardew: A Reader},
  publisher = {Copula},
  author    = {Cardew, Cornelius},
  editor    = {Prévost, Eddie},
  date      = {2006},
  origdate  = {1971},
}
```

with the option `cmsdate=both` you will get the output "(1971) 2006". Note that normally the year of the edition you read/cite should be the relevant date, nothing else.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,doi=true,url=true,isbn=false,datelabel=comp,cmsdate=both]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{cardew_treatise_1971,
  location  = {Essex},
  title     = {Treatise Handbook},
  pages     = {95--134},
  booktitle = {Cornelius Cardew: A Reader},
  publisher = {Copula},
  author    = {Cardew, Cornelius},
  editor    = {Prévost, Eddie},
  date      = {2006},
  origdate  = {1971},
}

@article{wooley_anthony_2016,
  title        = {Anthony Coleman and Survivors Breakfast Explore Treatise},
  volume       = {12},
  url          = {http://soundamerican.org/sa_archive/sa12/sa12-the-treatise-performances.html},
  journaltitle = {Sound American},
  author       = {Wooley, Nate},
  date         = {2016},
}

@article{wooley_mostly_2016,
  title        = {Mostly Other People Do The Killing Are Detained By Treatise},
  volume       = {12},
  url          = {http://soundamerican.org/sa_archive/sa12/sa12-the-treatise-performances.html},
  journaltitle = {Sound American},
  author       = {Wooley, Nate},
  date         = {2016},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{online}
    {}
    {\clearfield{urlyear}\clearfield{urlmonth}\clearfield{urlday}}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  bibliography = {References}
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

---

Alternatively you can use the `year` field instead of `date`. While `year` *should* be an integer/year number, `biblatex` accepts non-integer input and prints it as is.

With

```
@incollection{cardew_treatise_1971,
  location  = {Essex},
  title     = {Treatise Handbook},
  pages     = {95--134},
  booktitle = {Cornelius Cardew: A Reader},
  publisher = {Copula},
  author    = {Cardew, Cornelius},
  editor    = {Prévost, Eddie},
  year      = {1971 (2006)},
}

@article{wooley_anthony_2016,
  title        = {Anthony Coleman and Survivors Breakfast Explore Treatise},
  volume       = {12},
  url          = {http://soundamerican.org/sa_archive/sa12/sa12-the-treatise-performances.html},
  journaltitle = {Sound American},
  author       = {Wooley, Nate},
  year         = {2016a},
}

@article{wooley_mostly_2016,
  title        = {Mostly Other People Do The Killing Are Detained By Treatise},
  volume       = {12},
  url          = {http://soundamerican.org/sa_archive/sa12/sa12-the-treatise-performances.html},
  journaltitle = {Sound American},
  author       = {Wooley, Nate},
  year         = {2016b},
}
```

you get exactly the `year` fields printed. Sorting might be off though.

Comment: thank you! the `year` field was the best option.

Comment: @christopher If the answer helped you, please consider up-voting and accepting it, that is the preferred way to say thank you on this site. That way others can see that the answer helped you.

Comment: gerne, but how?

Comment: @christopher At the top left of the answer you should find an arrow up (to vote up) and an arrow down (to vote down), if you are the one who asked the question you should additionally find a checkmark below that to accept the answer. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour, http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers